# How to make interaction animation in Unity between two objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender

I created several objects in a blender: man, horse, dog, and others. I can animate them separately, like walking or running but I can not understand how to make the interaction animation between them in Unity, like riding a horse or pet a dog. To which object to apply this animation? Can you please describe or provide some tutorials for me?
I don't need already done solution, I want to realize how to make this on my own.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that.

The easier way to do that is to include a script with  public GameObject (consumers) variables in a GameObject (producer). With that reference, you can interact with other GameObjects.
You can drop the reference of the GamObject(consumers) on these public variables. These consumers will react to an action of the producer GameObject script.

[Example public GameObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXDgf.png)

However, I would really recommend you to use Events, it is a more elegant way to do the interaction between objects. 
Basically, one of the objects triggers an Event and the subscribers (other objects) will react in consequence to this event.